# Passing database name like variable

Tags: sql-server

Script is as below

```
SELECT *  FROM  table1 --working
SELECT *  FROM  xyz.dbo.table1--working
```

Instead of static database name , i need dynamically as mentioned below but it is not working, is there any way?

```
Declare @dbname varchar(10)
set @dbname ='xyz'
SELECT * FROM  tabl1e --working
SELECT * FROM  @dbname.dbo.table1--Not working
SELECT * FROM ['+@dbname+'].[dbo].table1--not working
```

**Error:**

```
Error Message:Invalid object name ''+@dbname+'.dbo.table1'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Dynamic SQL for that .

```
Declare @SQL Nvarchar(100),@dbname varchar(100) 
set @SQL = 'Select *  from '+ @dbname + '.dbo.table1'
Exec Sp_executeSQL @SQL
```

Comment: Msg :Incorrect syntax near '+@sourcedatabase+'.

        DECLARE    @sourcedatabase varchar(300) 

 
        SET @sourcedatabase='testing'     
 

        INSERT INTO  Table1
 SELECT  * 
 FROM  '+@sourcedatabase+'.dbo.table2

Answer (score 1):

This is always a tough one - most use, but I don't condone, dynamic sql.  If you know there are going to be limited concurrency issues, i.e. you specifically run it as a job, etc. you could use synonyms:

```
--CREATE SYNONYM
declare @environment int
IF @environment = 1
BEGIN
    CREATE SYNONYM tabl1e 
    FOR AdventureWorks2012.Production.tabl1e;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    CREATE SYNONYM tabl1e 
    FOR AdventureWorks2012.Development.tabl1e;
END

--Get Data
SELECT * FROM tabl1e

--DROP Synonym
DROP SYNONYM tabl1e
```

Problem with dynamic SQL is the compiler can never optimize, unless you force the server to always optimize adhoc queries - which is neither best practice nor default.

You can also check for synonym if you like, etc.

It is a way.

Comment: Horme: here also in select statement i need to pass database name as  static only? Thanks for Info.

Comment: No.  You can use a procedure and pass in the variable _Environment.